# how to fixed column with merge column header

Tags: html

how to fixed column no, area, category, sub category, and other column scroll left to right ?

```html
<table class="table table-bordered table-sm">
  <thead style="background:red;color:white">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">No</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Area</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Category</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Sub Category</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Risiko</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Cause</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Impact</th>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="6">Analisis</th>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="4">Evaluasi</th>
    <th rowspan="1" colspan="2">Risk Treatment Options</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Accountabel Unit</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Sumber Daya</th>
    <th rowspan="2">Deadline</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <th colspan="2">Probabilitas</th>
    <th colspan="2">Impact</th>
    <th colspan="2">Risk Level</th>
    <th>PIC</th>
    <th>Urgency</th>
    <th>Existing Control</th>
    <th>Risk Control<br>Assessment</th>
    <th>Proaktif</th>
    <th>Reaktif</th>
  </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>

</tbody>
</table>
```

JsFiddle Link: http://jsfiddle.net/5p77f171/

Comment: Please edit the question and put the code in the question.

Comment: i can't embed my code to answer, please help me this code here https://jsfiddle.net/5p77f171/3/?utm_source=website&utm_medium=embed&utm_campaign=5p77f171

Comment: I've updated your post with the code from your Fiddle and removed the Bootstrap tag as your question seems unrelated to that CSS framework.  You may still need to clarify what you're trying to achieve as your question is not very clear.